# How do you return a FLOAT from two INT's from an SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'm currently calculating the median of a table of numbers. I believe my code for calculating the median is correct however because the column i'm calculating it from is an INT the answer I get is an INT not a FLOAT. 
Just unsure what to add to the query so that a FLOAT is produced...

```
CREATE TABLE q4(
 Month      INT,
 Score      INT)

 INSERT INTO q4(Month, Score)
 VALUES (1,10), (2,5), (7,2), (8,6), (1,9), (4,11), (5,3), (9,10);


SELECT
(
 (SELECT MAX(Score) FROM
 (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Score FROM q4 ORDER BY Score) AS BottomHalf) 
 +
 (SELECT MIN(Score) FROM
 (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Score FROM q4 ORDER BY Score DESC) AS TopHalf)
) / 2 AS Median
```

Comment: Just to force `float` divide by `2.0`.

Comment: MSSQL, Sorry fairly new to SQL and not usre how to force a float...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CAST()`:

```
SELECT
CAST((
(
 (SELECT CAST(MAX(Score) as float) FROM
 (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Score FROM q4 ORDER BY Score) AS BottomHalf) 
 +
 (SELECT CAST(MIN(Score) as float) FROM
 (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Score FROM q4 ORDER BY Score DESC) AS TopHalf)
) / 2) as decimal(5,2)) AS Median
```

See <kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1e2c3/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your method of calculating the median requires sorting the data twice.  Here is another approach:

```
select avg(cast(score as float)) as median
from (select q.*, row_number() over (order by score) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from q4 q
     ) q
where (cnt % 2 = 1 and seqnum * 2 = (cnt + 1) or
       cnt % 2 = 0 and seqnum * 2 in (cnt - 1, cnt + 1));
```

It chooses one value when the number of rows is odd and two when the number of rows is even.  Your method also works.  I am just suggesting this as an alternative that doesn't require sorting the data twice.